# Code Sign error in xcodebuild archive

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

I am trying to generate a .ipa file only through command line,

```
xcodebuild archive -project someproject.xcodeproj -scheme somescheme -
archivePath /somepath/someproject.xcarchive
```

This command still depends on the provisioning profile I have selected in xcode, and fails if a wrong profile is chosen. 
The error generated is :

> Code Sign error: No matching provisioning profile found: Your build settings specify a provisioning profile with the UUID “some UUID”, however, no such provisioning profile was found.

Is there a way I can make archive command independent of provisioning profile chosen in Xcode ? Or can this be a configurable parameter in the command. Do we have a file where this value is mentioned, in that case I can overwrite it.

Comment: Did you find the solution? @sij

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should be able to use an additional parameter on the xcodebuild command you mentioned above.

There is an additional option called exportProvisioningProfile that allows you to specify the provisioning profile to use.

From Apple Docs:

-exportProvisioningProfile profilename
           Specifies the provisioning profile that should be used when exporting the archive.

Link to documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html

Comment: But export IPA is done after archiving, i am getting error in archiving itself

Comment: any help on this issue?

Comment: Any update on this? I couldn't find anywhere the solution, somebody suggest.